Why is my .NET 8.0 Blazor Web App not attempting a SignalR connection?
I have a simple dashboard application that I wrote in .NET 8.0 Blazor. There are various backend classes using timers to update parts of the page, it works as expected run through Visual Studio as a container, and standalone.
When deployed to an Azure Kubernetes cluster the page loads and shows the expected data, but the timers are not updating the page.
I can see from kubernetes logs that the timers are running, and I am not seeing exceptions.
When run locally I can see the expected SignalR negotiation, and messages exchanging in the browser network tab. I also see console messages in the browser:
[2024-08-11T22:46:43.501Z] Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 'https://localhost:32782/_blazor'.
blazor.web.js:1 [2024-08-11T22:46:43.543Z] Information: WebSocket connected to wss://localhost:32782/_blazor?id=uu8i0EXFbvgzUFqKBzgjug.

When deployed to kubernetes I cannot see any network tab activity related to SignalR, nor do I see any console messages.
The application is based heavily on the Blazor Web App VS template, using InteractiveServer mode, aside from the template code to hook up Blazor there is an MS EntraID based auth.
I'm looking for any insight into why the client JS script is not attempting to connect to the _blazor SignalR hub.
.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.1.35" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="8.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="8.0.7" NoWarn="NU1605" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.19.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="8.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Seq.Api" Version="2024.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Abridged program.cs looks like this:
builder.Services
    .AddRazorComponents()       
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
    .AddHubOptions(ho => {
        ho.EnableDetailedErrors = true;        
    });

builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders =
        ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
    {
        builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
            {
                
                context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri.Replace("http://", "https://");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });
    ...

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    app.UseHsts();
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseForwardedHeaders();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.Run();

Dockerfile looks like:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Dashboard/Dashboard.csproj", "Dashboard/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./Dashboard/Dashboard.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Dashboard"
RUN dotnet build "./Dashboard.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./Dashboard.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Dashboard.dll"]

Ingress currently looks like this:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: systems-dashboard-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "affinity"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "14400"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "14400"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-http-version: "1.1"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - {mysite}
  rules:
  - host:  {mysite}
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: systems-dashboard
            port:
              number: 8080

I have added ingress annotations per this MS article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/server?view=aspnetcore-8.0#kubernetes
and this SO article:
How to correctly deploy a Blazor Server app on Kubernetes
I have put a breakpoint in the blazor.web.js source in the browser, and attempted to step through the issue. Function names are obfuscated so its rather hard to see what's going on.
I sent post request to https://{mysite}/_blazor/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1 and got back
{
    "negotiateVersion": 1,
    "connectionId": "DdFgDoSqHeNzcYb_byCMkA",
    "connectionToken": "TL4xt2O-Z4xIFOIQvNG6YA",
    "availableTransports": [
        {
            "transport": "WebSockets",
            "transferFormats": [
                "Text",
                "Binary"
            ]
        },
        {
            "transport": "ServerSentEvents",
            "transferFormats": [
                "Text"
            ]
        },
        {
            "transport": "LongPolling",
            "transferFormats": [
                "Text",
                "Binary"
            ]
        }
    ]
}


I can't find this line app.MapBlazorHub();. May I know if you have this in your code ?

@JasonPan app.MapBlazorHub() is not required in .net 8.0. See https://akifmt.github.io/dotnet/2024-01-20-blazor-.net8-migrating-app-from-.net-6-or-.net-7-to-.net-8/

To test this further I created a new project which is the unaltered .NET 8.0 Blazor Web App with server interactive render mode. I deployed this to K8s with the exact same helm charts as before. The result is the same as my  dashboard app. Pages load, but no interactive functions, and no signalr type negotiations attempted with the server.
Also tried deploying the WebAssembly template, with the exact same result (but there we would not expect SignalR negotiations)

Hi @user1890407, please kindly check the issue Blazor Server does not work after upgrade to .NET 8.0 in github. And try to use blazor.server.js, not blazor.web.js, check _blazor exist or not after being deployed to  kubernetes.

Thank you for your response @JasonPan.
I looked at the link, and was hopeful, but it refers to blazor server app, where I can see mine is a Blazor web app. I was not aware of the distinction before now. There is no access to head or body, and the blazor script is not referenced in a way that I can change it.
_blazor exists, and does respond to negociation, the final code block in the original question is the response to this call.
